# Howto generate function index with Doxygen

Tags: doxygen

I'm using Doxygen 1.8.14 (on Gentoo) generating documentation for a large Qt project.

If I set ALPHABETICAL_INDEX to YES (the default), I get a class index - a page with all classes on one page. I have failed to find a setting that generates a page with **all functions on one page** - I only get a page for each letter.

I stumbled on documentation generated by Doxygen 1.8.4 that seemed to have this, but not for later versions.

**Added:** If you, in the menu select Classes => Class members => Functions without selecting a letter, you get to the URL "../html/functions_func.html" - which seems right. What happens (in my case) is that functions starting with "a" are listed on `functions_func.html` instead of all functions. Functions starting with "b" are listed on `functions_func_b.html` and so on for c, d ... - as expected. `functions_func_a.html` is just missing.

Looking at the [Doxygen Smarty template](https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/blob/master/templates/html/htmlindexpages.tpl) used,  I don't see how this can happen - that `functions_func.html` doesn't contain all functions, and that `functions_func_a.html` is missing. This is starting to smell like a bug - but the Smarty code looks right.

Comment: Which settings did you use? Did you have a look at GENERATE_TREEVIEW, DISABLE_INDEX ?

Comment: Yes - tried both. The treeview is just another presentation of the navigation.

Comment: Is there a public accessible part where I can see the mentioned output?

Comment: Not my project, but I guess https://itk.org/Doxygen/html/functions_func.html is a good enough (random) example. I know that I can use the search to find a function, but I really expected to have a (optional) "function index" too.

Comment: I think I can see what you mean now, it is still present for the "Class index", other places I have not been able to check yet.

Comment: Yes, class index is no problem. I'm starting to wonder if it is a bug. I expected functions_func.html to contain all functions. What happens (in my case) is that functions starting with "a" are listed on functions_func.html, functions starting with "b" are listed on functions_func_b.html and so on. (functions_func_a.html is missing.) I have even updated to Doxygen 1.8.14 now.

Answer (score 1):

Doxygen does not have a feature to generate a function index. Period.

An index for a printed book shows all of the pages on which each indexed word appears. Doxygen provides only an alphabetized function (word) list. But it does not provide for each function (word) a list of places (pages) where that function (word) is used. It turns out that to provide this type of indexing functionality would require technology equivalent to a compiler, which is clearly out of scope for the Doxygen project.

Comment: Based on what and which doxygen version are you coming to this conclusion? In e.g. https://doxygen.github.io/doxygen/globals_func.htmlI see a list of function.

Comment: @albert Your link (slightly broken) is to a function list. This is not a cross-reference in the sense of an index of where the functions are used, just a list of functions.

Comment: @JonathanBen-Avraham: So you are saying that I should file a feature request ;-) It should by easy as Doxygen clearly generates a function index per letter. Random example: https://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/functions_func_g.html 
I'm still surprised that https://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/functions.html doesn't "work" as https://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classes.html

Comment: @hansfn An index for a printed book shows all of the pages on which each indexed word appears. Doxygen provides only an alphabetized function (word) list. It does not provide for each function (word) a list of places (pages) where that function (word) is used. It turns out that to provide this type of indexing functionality would require technology equivalent to a compiler.

Comment: Doxygen has the `\addindex` command it says in the documentation "\addindex (text)            This command adds (text) to the LATEX , DocBook and RTF index.". For an example see the Index at the end of the doxygen pdf documentation. For HTML this functionality is not present, though a (limited) version is possible over the search field (see the doxygen internal documentation: https://doxygen.github.io/doxygen/index.html). At least this is what I understood of the requirements / comments mentioned in the question / answer / comments.

Comment: @JonathanBen-Avraham I'm not asking for an index for where each function is used, just a list of all function (in all classes) on one page - as written in bold on my post. I haven't used Doxygen for a while so maybe this is fixed? It's just a simple thing.

Comment: @albert Your example link is, as I have pointed out, just for the letter a - not all functions. I'm trying to avoid making a script that merges all the separate single letter pages to one page ;-)